# dash of python library shapash is not working

Tags: python, plotly-dash, kaggle

I have used Shapash library for visualization but the dash is not working. The code is running and also gave a dash link, which shows

```
Dash is running on http://0.0.0.0:8050/

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/shapash/webapp/smart_app.py:307: FutureWarning:

Using short name for 'orient' is deprecated. Only the options: ('dict', list, 'series', 'split', 'records', 'index') will be used in a future version. Use one of the above to silence this warning.
```

```
 * Serving Flask app 'shapash.webapp.smart_app' (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: off
```

after clicking the dash link, it is showing

" This site can’t be reached The webpage at http://0.0.0.0:8050/ might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently to a new web address.
ERR_ADDRESS_INVALID "

I was using kaggle for the execution. Can anyone help me.

Comment: May you please share your code example to run this? Rather difficult to reproduce without it

Comment: here is the link of the notebook:  [link](https://www.kaggle.com/code/hafsakibria/notebook3f61b7a6f6) @DanielAlMouiee